# Can I use Code Connection tool with non-educational version of Minecraft (iPad)?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It is not quite clear for me - can I use Code Connection tool (installed on my Mac) with the standard (non-educational) version of Minecraft (installed on my iPad Pro)? When I try to connect from iPad to Code Connect, I get an error - connection failed. Both devices are in the same local network. 'Cheats' and 'Education Edition' features are enabled when the new World is created on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, while I'm not 100% sure of this, I think code connection attempts a check against the version of Minecraft that connects and immediately disconnects if it isn't Education Edition or Win 10 Edition. My Android device connects to my code connection on my Win 10 machine, but then immediately disconnects. Connecting from another machine with Win10 edition works, so sadly it looks like code connection is version locked.

Seems like a poor decision on Microsoft's part.